# spring data neo4j doesn understand dot '.' in parameter

Tags: neo4j, spring-data

Please, help with this query:

```
@Query("MATCH (n:User{userId:1})--(friends) return friends order by {type}")
Iterable<Map<String, Object>> getLastFriendsByLevel(@Param("userId") long userId, @Param("type") String type);
```

When `type = "friends.level"`, the result is not sorted by level as expected. It seems ordering does not work when parameter "type" contains '.'.

What is wrong?

Comment: you can't parameterize node or relationship property keys, you'll have to write the `friends.level` in the query itself

Comment: Thanks. What about @Query("MATCH (n:User{userId:1})--(friends) return friends order by friends.{type}") Iterable> getLastFriendsByLevel(@Param("userId") long userId, @Param("type") String type)   it doesn't not work too, when type="level"?   Or, is there any other way to pass parameter in ordering clause?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand in it's current state. Please see [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question.

Comment: @DmitryRomov you're still trying to parameterize a property key ;-) friends is node and {type} is the property key, it is just not possible and not supported by the Cypher language.

Comment: Yes, I've just got that). Thanks, Christophe. Have a nice day!

Comment: Actually, it should be possible. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
@Query("MATCH (n:User{userId: {userId}})--(friends) return friends order by friends[{key}]")
Iterable<Map<String, Object>> getLastFriendsByLevel(@Param("userId") long userId, @Param("key") String key);
```

This query actually uses the `userId` parameter, and it uses the `key` parameter value (e.g., "level") to `ORDER BY` that `friends` key.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot for the perfect unusual suggestion. It saves much time.